# How do I "add" the c/c++ package to the eclipse for java ee developers?

Tags: java, c++, c, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Ok here is the question. I don't want to have two eclipses, I just want to have one for c/c++ and Java EE. In the packages comparison link at eclipse.org is a list with the features per package. As can be seen there I think that if I have the "JAVA EE" I just need to add "EGit", "Linux Tools" and "CDT" in order to have both complete packages.

But I ask, is this that transparent? Just add those and that's it?

If this is true, how can I do that? Just add those three to the Java EE I already have? I mean what would be the procedure to achieve this integration?

Comment: Here is the feature comparison chart: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php It also contains a link to a page with instructions on how to install missing components: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-124.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's it. Btw you don't need EGit properly speaking. EGit is for Eclipse integration with Git repositories and has nothing to do with Java and/or C++.

IMHO I strongly suggest you having one Eclipse for Java and another one for C++. This way you can install relevant plugins for each one and not oversaturate Eclipse with plugins, which consume a lot of memory.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that, but if that's the only concern I'd rather like to have one for everything, I think is more clean. This unless there are other critical issues having one eclipse for all

Comment: Well, it's up to you, but I **really** suggest having separate ones. Eclipse is very memory hungry, and the more plugins and projects you have open on one session, the slower it will be. But as I said: your call. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

I use Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3RC2) on Ubuntu. Here are the steps I installed C++ plugins:

```
    Help > Eclipse Marketplaces..
    Find: C++, press Enter
    Scroll down to locate Eclipse C/C++ IDE CDT 9.2 (Neon.2)
    Click Install
```

Note: you may see different C/C++ IDE CDT version if you have a different version of Eclipse Java EE IDE

[image]